# Aurelia view-model testing

Tags: karma-runner, aurelia

I would like to be able to test Aurelia view models. I have tried doing it as described:
http://patrickwalters.net/unit-testing-your-es6-view-models-my-best-practices-for-aurelia/
... but the current Aurelia-templating library does not support the createForUnitTest method/function call. I was wondering if there is an alternative. The docs in Aurelia.io docs does not have any docs on view model testing.

I greatly appreciate any input/update